# Theoretical questions about layers in dnn with batchnormalization using keras

Tags: keras, batch-normalization

I have some troubles to understand the models of DNN using batchnormalization, in specifique using keras. Can somebody explaind me the structure and content of each layer in this model that I built?

```
modelbatch = Sequential()
modelbatch.add(Dense(512, input_dim=1120))
modelbatch.add(BatchNormalization())
modelbatch.add(Activation('relu'))
modelbatch.add(Dropout(0.5))

modelbatch.add(Dense(256))
modelbatch.add(BatchNormalization())
modelbatch.add(Activation('relu'))
modelbatch.add(Dropout(0.5))

modelbatch.add(Dense(num_classes))
modelbatch.add(BatchNormalization())
modelbatch.add(Activation('softmax'))
# Compile model
modelbatch.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Train the model
start = time.time()
model_info = modelbatch.fit(X_2, y_2, batch_size=500, \
                         epochs=20, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
end = time.time()
```

This is, i think, all the layers of my model:

```
print(modelbatch.layers[0].get_weights()[0].shape)
(1120, 512)
print(modelbatch.layers[0].get_weights()[1].shape)
(512,)
print(modelbatch.layers[1].get_weights()[0].shape)
(512,)
print(modelbatch.layers[1].get_weights()[1].shape)
(512,)
print(modelbatch.layers[1].get_weights()[2].shape)
(512,)
print(modelbatch.layers[1].get_weights()[3].shape)
(512,)
print(modelbatch.layers[4].get_weights()[0].shape)
(512, 256)
print(modelbatch.layers[4].get_weights()[1].shape)
(256,)
print(modelbatch.layers[5].get_weights()[0].shape)
(256,)
print(modelbatch.layers[5].get_weights()[1].shape)
(256,)
print(modelbatch.layers[5].get_weights()[2].shape)
(256,)
print(modelbatch.layers[5].get_weights()[3].shape)
(256,)
print(modelbatch.layers[8].get_weights()[0].shape)
(256, 38)
print(modelbatch.layers[8].get_weights()[1].shape)
(38,)
print(modelbatch.layers[9].get_weights()[0].shape)
(38,)
print(modelbatch.layers[9].get_weights()[1].shape)
(38,)
print(modelbatch.layers[9].get_weights()[2].shape)
(38,)
print(modelbatch.layers[9].get_weights()[3].shape)
(38,)
```

I will appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through your model:

You have your input layer with dimension 1120, connected to that one, you have your first hidden layer with 512 neurons, after you have your batch normalization layer. After that your activation function and after that your dropout layer. Note that you can use the command `model.summary()` to visualize your model

In theory, you can (and should), consider these layer only like one layer on which you apply the following transformation: batch-normalization, activation and dropout. In practice, each layer is implemented individually in Keras because you gain in modularity for the implementation: instead of coding all the possible way a layer can be designed, the user can choose to add to the layer batch norm or dropout. To look at the modular implementation, I recommend you to have a look at http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture4.pdf and in general at http://cs231n.stanford.edu/syllabus.html if you want to gain deeper knowledge.

For the batch-normalization layer, you have as you can notice 4 parameters: two adjustable parameters: gamma and beta, and two parameters that are set by the data (the mean and the standard deviation). To learn what it is, look at the Stanford class, you can also find it in the original paper about batch normalization https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167. It is just a trick to improve learning speed and improve accuracy by normalizing your data at each layer, like you would do it in a preprocessing step for your input data.

From what I said, you can infer the rest of your model.

N-B: I wouldn't use the batchnormalization layer in the last step before the softmax.

Is it clearer ?

Comment: yes!, thanks, it's clearer, but just the 4 parameters of batch-normalization, I don't know if I could use to evaluate with another data (how you know, it's possible to save models in keras or in the case of a simple DNN you can take the weights and bias with model.layers.get_weights() to evalute another data), so, I will like to make the same thing, in this case using batch normalization, but I don't know which of all layers showed is necessary to take for evaluate in another environment? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean you want to use the model you learned to make prediction without the Keras API and you want to copy all your weights and architecture into something else ?

Comment: yes, like for exemple with a simple DNN I get the weights with this:  `weights1 = modelbatch.layers[0].get_weights()[0]` #The 1 hidden layer
`biases1 =... `
`weights2 = modelbatch.layers[1].get_weights()[0]` #The 2 hidden layer
`biases2 = .....`
`weights3 = modelbatch.layers[4].get_weights()[0]` #The output layer
`biases3 =....`

Comment: And with all that, I can predict in another environment with the same accuracy that I got in keras, but my difficulty is when I add a batch normalization layer, because as you know there are 4 weights "layers" of each batch normalization that I've used. I hope my description is clear. Thanks!!

Comment: According to the source code https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py, you have the following attributes: `moving_mean`, `moving_variance`, `beta` and `gamma`.